# How do I set the version visible in 'Programs and Features'?

Tags: wix

I need to set the version visible in the 'Programs and Features' dialog in Windows.  I know that this version doesn't have to follow the *major*.*minor*.*build*.*revision* restriction (for example, wxPython shows '2.8.12.1-unicode' in its 'Version' column), but when I attempt to set the Version attribute in the Product element I get the following error:

```
Product.wxs(50,0): error CNDL0108: The Product/@Version attribute's value, '2.3.4.0-55628f206205451282ae6060d9305254bd79cb87', is not a valid version.  Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer from 0 to 65534.
```

There must be a different property but I can't find it in the Wix documentation.

*How do I set this version visible in Wix to an arbitrary string?*

EDIT:

See the image below to see some of the different version schemes that don't follow the Windows Installer standard (wxPython, Windows Driver Package*, Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK). [image]

Comment: There is no standard on what the displayed version string is. Windows Installer is just being helpful. It doesn't use anything that it writes into the uninstall registry key. It just uninstalls it when appropriate to follow its own specification. Windows Installer doesn't provide any direct way of overriding the default value. It would be interesting if any of the installers you point out are Windows Installer packages.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Installer doesn't support having separate product version and display versions.

Comment: Bob, thanks for answering my question and based on your current job you would know what's going on!  So if your answer is true, why do installers have versions that don't follow the Windows Installer standard versioning spec (see the image in my initial question above)?

Comment: It's a Windows Installer limitation that the display version is always the version of the package. wxPython, for example, doesn't use Windows Installer, so it can write an arbitrary string for the display version.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the .Net setup project look for Version under "Deployment Project Properties".

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are referring to with "Programs and Features"? Are you talking about "Add/Remove Programs" in Windows, or are you talking about the dialogs in your setup?

I suppose you can have a look here: [Configuring Add/Remove Programs with Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but without knowing more I don't  quite know if this is what you are asking.

Please be aware that this list of programs and applications does not come from just one registry location. I do believe that it is **not possible** to override the version field for Windows Installer packages whether they are built using Wix or other tools. If the installation is done with non-MSI setups, I suppose they can set the version field as they see fit, but Windows Installer enforces restrictions. Perhaps you can set the **ARPCOMMENTS** property to a value indicating what you want to indicate.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying MSI property that shows up in Add/Remove Programs aka Programs&Features is the ProductVersion property and it does have to follow a numeric format:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may be able to get a text version to show if you create a DisplayVersion text string in the Uninstall registry key. I suggest you look at the wxPython entry in the Uninstall key to see what's in DisplayVersion rather than in the binary Version value.

Comment: I too would like to know if this is possible. I would also like to know why you want to display something custom there - to get an understanding of your release strategy.

Comment: @Glytzhkof The installer is a "component" of the software product like a DLL. Its version has no value to the user. There is no reason to display it. What should be shown is a string that has marketing value as well a certain uniqueness that helps the user communicate with tech support. That string should the only version string the user sees anywhere.